# Using NSURLSessionDataTask, can I resume downloading a file, even if user comes back after quitting an App?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessiontask

Suppose, I am downloading a file of 300 MB using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` or `NSURLSessionDataTask` (at present, I don’t know which is the best choice in my case). User quits the App or App suddenly crashed while 250 MB were downloaded. When next time, when user opens the App, I would have to resume downloading from 250 MB.

I have made a demo using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`. But, if we are using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, we don't have access to the `NSURL` of the temporary file until the download is complete (and in `didFinishDownloadingToURL` we would move this temporary file to its permanent final location).

I came to know that, I will have to use an `NSURLSessionDataTask` rather than a `DownloadTask`, then use the delegate method on `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
```

This will allow me to access the data as it is received. But, I don’t know how would I manage things now onward. I want a way, so that I can append data in above delegate and write it on disk at some location. Second question, how would I know that the downloading of a data should start from here only (i.e. from 250 MB)

Is it really feasible? Or it is feasible only if the App is in active state?

I am desperate to this question.